# group by sum of counts based on values in another column in Pandas

Tags: pandas

My table looks like

```
origin   Ad_Block1.    Ad_Block2
YT.      Yes.          Yes
YT.      Yes.          Yes
YT.      Yes
FB.      Yes
FB.      Yes
FB.      Yes
FB.      Yes
```

I have a variable storing the sum of the count of Yes

For example, 
yes_count  = 9

My expected output is

```
Origin   Ad_Block_Count 
YT.      5
FB.      4
```

How can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of counting `Yes` and/or `Yes.` values specifically, the following approach simply counts the number of non-null entries of each `origin` across all `Ad_Block` columns. If "no" is represented by a missing value, this should be fine.

Assuming your DataFrame is named `df`:

```
# Replace empty strings with np.nan
df = df.replace('', np.nan)

# "Melt" the DataFrame such that each value in each column
# is moved into its own row.
df.melt(id_vars='origin').groupby('origin')['value'].count()

origin
FB.    4
YT.    5
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stack the dataframe, check if the data starts with `Yes` and `groupby().sum()`:

```
(df.set_index('origin')
   .stack().str.startswith('Yes')
   .groupby(level=0).sum()
)
```

Output:

```
origin
FB.    4.0
YT.    5.0
dtype: float64
```